# Should i create a temporary 'check_out' DB table when a user decides to check out?

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I am building an e-comm site with a database shopping cart approach using a cookie as a unique identifier. I am wondering if i should be creating a temporary checkout table to store the users shopping cart data for when the user decides to checkout? I want to try and separate the actual shopping cart from the checkout process in case the user may open a second page and try to add additional cart items while in the later stages of the checkout process.

I have a loop in place that constantly updates the checkout order summary if a user tries to add additional cart items from separate page, but when the user makes a payment they are redirected off site to a securepay payments page where they enter their payment information, so it's possible to add additional cart items during this stage.

Should i be creating a temporary checkout table that stores the current shopping cart at the beggining of the users checkout process?

I was thinking about just locking the cart when the user goes into the checkout process using sessions, so that if the the user abandons their cart, the cart will become unlocked when the session is destroyed. But i don't know, it seems less reliable?

Can anyone give advice on how i can approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the suggestions :

- Don't use cookies and session for storing cart items, use a separate
  table for this.  This way regardless of sessions, the cart will be
  same.
- Try to rely less on cookies and session, and use database instead.
  Many carts use database sessions instead of using php sessions.

Comment: I do store all the cart_id and shopping_cart items in the database, the cookie is just for a unique identifier